# Why two $push inside one update is not working in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

when i am updating two arrays separately, its working fine. But when i am updating together, only 2nd array is updating

```
var selection = {
    _id : {$in : membersIds}
};

var update = {
    $push : {
      notifications_Array_Object : newNotification
    },
    $push : {
      groups_Array_Object : ObjectID(groupId)
    },
    $inc : {unreadNotifications_Integer : 1}
};
userDb.update(selection,update,{multi : true}, function (error,result) {
    ...
});
```

when userDb.update() is used separately for  notifications_Array_Object and groups_Array_Object, its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your query

**From:**

```
var update = {
    $push : {
      notifications_Array_Object : newNotification
    },
    $push : {
      groups_Array_Object : ObjectID(groupId)
    },
    $inc : {unreadNotifications_Integer : 1}
};
```

**To:**

```
var update = {
    $push : {
      notifications_Array_Object : newNotification, groups_Array_Object : ObjectID(groupId)
    }
    $inc : {unreadNotifications_Integer : 1}
};
```